# PowerApps SharePoint App In Citrix Secure Hub

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing, powerapp

We're creating a PowerApp that connects to a SharePoint Online list.  Our requirement from security is that it published as an app in Citrix Secure Hub on mobile devices.

Is it possible to publish PowerApps in Citrix Secure Hub?